# How to use Accumulate on a matrix column

Tags: list-manipulation

For a matrix

```
{{1,a},{2,b},{3,c},{4,d}},
```

how do I use the command `Accumulate` to get the matrix

```
{{1,a},{2,a+b},{3,a+b+c},{4, a+b+c+d}}?
```

One can break apart the matrix

```
list1={1,2,3,4} and list2 = {a,b,c,d}
```

and let

```
list3=Accumulate[list2]
```

and then let

```
list4=Transpose[{list1,list3}]
```

This gives what I want.

Is there a more direct way?

Comment: The steps can be combined `Transpose[{list[[All, 1]], Accumulate@list[[All, 2]]}]`.

Answer (score 11):

**Using `SubsetMap`:**

```
amat = {{1, a}, {2, b}, {3, c}, {4, d}}
SubsetMap[Accumulate, amat, {All, 2}]
```

**Using `FoldList`:**

```
FoldList[{First@#2, Last@#1 + Last@#2} &, amat]
```

---

Result:

> {{1, a}, {2, a + b}, {3, a + b + c}, {4, a + b + c + d}}

---

**Using `Construct` and `MapThread`:**

To apply different functions to columns, let's start with  with a 3-column example matrix called `bmat`.

```
bmat = {{1, a, w}, {2, b, x}, {3, c, y}, {4, d, z}}
funcs = {Identity, Accumulate, #^2 &};
Transpose@MapThread[Construct, {funcs, Transpose@bmat}] // TableForm
```

> {{1, a, w^2}, {2, a + b, x^2}, {3, a + b + c, y^2}, {4, a + b + c + d,
> z^2}}

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & a & w^2 \\
 2 & a+b & x^2 \\
 3 & a+b+c & y^2 \\
 4 & a+b+c+d & z^2 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Why doesn't   MapAt[Accumulate, amat, {All, 2}]  work?  I tried this.

Comment: It applies to individual locations. `MapAt[f, amat, {All, 2}]`.

Answer (score 10):

Another possibility:

```
list = {{1,a},{2,b},{3,c},{4,d}};

list[[All,2]] = Accumulate[list[[All,2]]];
```

Then `list` has the desired output:

```
list
```

> {{1, a}, {2, a + b}, {3, a + b + c}, {4, a + b + c + d}}

Comment: Why the downvote?  And (once again) no explanatory comment.

Answer (score 2):

Using `MapAt`:

```
amat = {{1, a}, {2, b}, {3, c}, {4, d}}
Transpose@MapAt[Accumulate, Transpose@amat, {2}]
(*{{1, a}, {2, a + b}, {3, a + b + c}, {4, a + b + c + d}}*)
```

Or using `Table` and `Partition`:

```
Table[{amat[[i, 1]], Total@(First@Partition[amat[[All, 2]], amat[[i, 1]]])}, {i, 1, Length[amat]}]
(*{{1, a}, {2, a + b}, {3, a + b + c}, {4, a + b + c + d}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Some other methods

**Query**

```
Module[{i=0},Query[All, {2 -> (i+=#&)}]]@mat

(* {{1, a}, {2, a + b}, {3, a + b + c}, {4, a + b + c + d}} *)
```

The 'compiled form' of `Query` here uses `MapAt` 'under the hood'

```
Query[All, {2 -> (i+=#&)}]//Normal

MapAt[i += #1 & , {All, 2}]
```

**MapAt**

```
Module[{i=0},MapAt[i+=#&,{All,2}]]@mat

(* {{1, a}, {2, a + b}, {3, a + b + c}, {4, a + b + c + d}} *)
```

**ApplyTo** and **Accumulate**

Using a modification of the neat method posted [below](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/277703/106) by Carl Woll (without in-place modification):

```
Module[{temp=#},temp[[All,2]]//=Accumulate;temp]&@mat

{{1, a}, {2, a + b}, {3, a + b + c}, {4, a + b + c + d}}
```

**Matrix**

```
mat={{1,a},{2,b},{3,c},{4,d}};
```